# cant see the html page when navigating to /home or new. Only index is showing

Tags: javascript, angular

In this project I am trying to learn Angular and nesting components. For some reason I can't navigate to /home page. The page is not showing. Any help please. Thank you.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home' },
  { path: 'home', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'view/:id', component: ShowComponent },
  { path: 'new', component: NewComponent },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditComponent },
  { path: '**', component: IndexComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your code to

```
[{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home' // you dont need /home
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: IndexComponent
  }
]
```